# White fungus on tree

Tags: fungus

How to save a peepal tree ("Sacred Fig" or "Bodhi Tree") from white fungus growth on its trunk. Is it safe for the tree to remove the extra growth. What medication or treatment  need to be given. Please help save the tree.

Comment: A photo of the tree and the fungus would help

Comment: Definitely need a photo or two, not least to see what type of fungal growth there is and where it is on the trunk